# Python 2.7 and pip install realted issues with _markerlib and installing other packages failures

Tags: python, pip, installation

Currently trying to install some web framework but it fails with following error. It also shows the same error when I try to install other packages as well. I can't figure out where it stems from. Any ideas would help a lot.

```
 PS D:\Python_Programming_Zed_Show\Exersize_46\Python27_Projects\Exersize_48\Exersize_48> python -m pip install lpthw.web
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/late
    st/development/release-process/#python-2-support
    Collecting lpthw.web
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/0d/a200087bb551895143fedfb5f7df416ccb7ecb46428e04dd011a7ea19689/lpthw.web-1.1.tar.gz
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'D:\Python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'d:\\users\\arhitect\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-gj9eke\\lpthw.web\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'d:\\users\\arhitect\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-gj9eke\\lpthw.web\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tok
    enize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
             cwd: d:\users\arhitect\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-gj9eke\lpthw.web\
        Complete output (28 lines):
        running egg_info
        creating pip-egg-info\lpthw.web.egg-info
        writing pip-egg-info\lpthw.web.egg-info\PKG-INFO
        writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\lpthw.web.egg-info\top_level.txt
        writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\lpthw.web.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "d:\users\arhitect\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-gj9eke\lpthw.web\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
            platforms=["any"],
          File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 177, in run
            writer = ep.load(installer=installer)
          File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2241, in load
            if require: self.require(env, installer)
          File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2254, in require
            working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
          File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2471, in requires
            dm = self._dep_map
          File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2682, in _dep_map
            self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
          File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2699, in _compute_dependencies
            from _markerlib import compile as compile_marker
        ImportError: No module named _markerlib
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    PS D:\Python_Programming_Zed_Show\Exersize_46\Python27_Projects\Exersize_48\Exersize_48>
```

Comment: I went through that post, when I try to import markerlib in idle, it does import, that was puzzles me. If markerlib is not installed how then it gets imported?

Comment: Are you sure your IDLE uses the same Python? Packages in Python are not global, every Python installed at the host has its own set of packages.

Comment: well, I run the IDLE exactly for python 2.7, I go directly to systems folder, find idlelib folder and run the idle.exe or .bat, then the IDLE pops up and inside its written:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ActivePython 2.7.14.2717 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 15 2017, 16:31:45) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import lexicon

Comment: What systems folder? `D:\Python27\Scripts`?

Comment: D:\Python27\Lib\idlelib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic import comes from `distribute-0.7.3` which is outdated package and should not be used. Remove the directory `d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3`.

Comment: Hello phd, I removed the distribute then I uninstalled it and reinstalled and now seems that everything works. I have doubts that it was also messing up with python 3.7 on system. 

What would be interesting to know, if I have python27 and python37 installed on my machine, and I add the suitable paths to my system Environmental Variables, also "pip" gets added as part of it. 

So, in this case if we are running pip command in powershell/cmd, which pip is then run by system? the one in python 27 or python37? or its the same for both

Comment: The first one found in `%PATH%`. To work around the limitation at unix/linux the name the scripts `pip-2.7` and `pip-3.7`. And at w32 they created a wrapper named `py.exe`. Use it like `py -2.7 python -m pip`; `py` looks up the named version. May be even `py -2.7 pip` but I'm not sure — I'm not a w32 user. AFAIK `py` doesn't look into `%PATH%`, it looks for Python versions in the registry.